# Difference between static void main(string[] args) and static void main() in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application

can u pls anyone tel me,
Difference between static void main(string[] args) and static void main() in c#?

Comment: One takes command-line arguments, and the other ignores them? I'm not sure what else you're asking for here.

Comment: thank u for ur answer... what is mean by command-lines arguments?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments

Comment: thanks fro your response..

Comment: Main method is the entry point to the program , declaring parameters into main method allows to accept arguments from command-line (in your console , type classname argument1 argument2).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that obvious ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Takes an `array of string` as parameter.

```
static void Main()
```

Doesn't take any parameter.By the way in `C#` correct name  of the main method is **Main** (upper-case **M**) unlike `java`.

In the first method, `string[] args` allows you to pass arguments to your main method when you executing your program in `command-line`.For example consider this example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

If you build this program, then open the command line (cmd.exe), go to directory of your program (directory that contains *.exe file) with `CD` command and execute it like this:

```
Program.exe Hello World
```

You will this output:

```
Hello
World
```

Note: You should change `Program.exe` with your executable file name.And also you can write it without extension, like `Program "Hello World"`